# Why does the browser ignore css specificity rules for the printer mediaquery?

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I'm trying to show a specific div on printer-output while blocking out all the other site elements (also the ones including my div). 
Normally I would go by using:

```
<div class="container"> 
  Please don't show other containing elements
  <div id="element">
    Please show on printer
  </div>
</div>
```

So since the container div is styled by a class, its specificity is lower than the one of the element div. Therefore this should work:

```
   @media print {
     .container { display: none; }
     #element { display: block; }
   }
```

I also tried to use **!important** on the #element selector, but the printer-preview of Firefox and Chrome are ignoring me.
It absolutely confuses me, because for @media screen {} this ist working perfectly fine.

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with specificity. It is simply how `display` works.

If an element is not displayed, then its children are not displayed either.

From [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#box-generation):

> **none**: The element and its descendants generates no boxes.

You can see that with a demo using screen:

```css
     .container {
       display: none;
     }
     #element {
       display: block;
     }
```

```html
<p>Start</p>
<div class="container">
  Please don't show other containing elements
  <div id="element">
    Please show on printer
  </div>
</div>
<p>Fin</p>
```

Comment: But it is totally working inside the @media screen media-query ?

Comment: @ShinyTaris — No, it isn't. Demo added to the answer.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. Lost a closing } for my @media screen which causes this misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. `display: none` hides all the children inside the parent. You can use `visibility:hidden` something like:

```
@media print {
    .container { visibility: hidden; }
    #element { visibility: visible; }
}
```

demo:

```css
.container {
  visibility: hidden;  
}
#element {
  visibility: visible;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  Please don't show other containing elements
  <div id="element">
    Please show on printer
  </div>
</div>
```